# Layer tick boxes embedded in PDF map

Tags: layers, pdf

Maybe this is more of a PDF question than a GIS question.

Today, I received a layered PDF map shown as a landscape A3, with a square map on the left, and with the map title, the legend, the scale, a tiny overview map etc. on the right-hand side. However, each legend item had two tick boxes beside it: one for switching on/off the symbols and one for switching on/off the labels. It also contained radio buttons to switch between various background maps. I thought this was really elegant, and would like to create something similar.

I know how to create a layered PDF in ArcGIS, and then go to the Layers toolbar in Adobe Reader to switch on/off layers in the map. However, I'd like to know how I can embed the layer control inside the map.

(Note: I am not looking on how to draw individual tick and radio boxes, as I feel it's done by some application (semi-)automatically)

EDIT:
Here is a picture of it, cut down to the bare minimum for copyright reasons

[image: Tick boxes and radio button in PDF map]

Comment: Are you able to include a picture of the PDF into your Question?  My first thought is that it might come from a TerraGo product - http://www.terragotech.com/

Comment: I have added a picture

Comment: When you open the PDF in Acrobat, can you then turn them on and off using the "Layers/Optional Content Groups ("OCGs") panel on the left side of the screen? If so, these layers are indeed OCGs, and then it is possible to control them using Acrobat JavaScript, and it is also possible to add fields to the PDF where you can control the OCGs.

Comment: @Max: They are listed in the Layers, but they are locked down in Adobe Reader (of course in Adobe Acrobat I can override that).
The question is thus what application generates this JavaScript, as I don't feel this is someone's homebrew.

Comment: You would have to provide the JavaScript, and for adding the fields etc. to the document, you would use Acrobat.